# SPSS python - writing Unicode to spss syntax file

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, spss

I am using python to write a text to an .sps file (which is SPSS syntax file).

```
begin program.
outfile=open("c:/temp/syntax.sps","w+")
outfile.write("some text…")
outfile.close()
end program.
```

The last character in the text is:

```
>>> my_text="some text…"
>>> my_text[-1]
'\x85'
```

If I open the resulting file in Notepad++, I see the text correctly. However, if I open the file in SPSS syntax, I see this:

```
some textâ€¦
```

Is there a quick way around this, using only the native modules of python 2.7 ? I would rather not convert all unicodes into their some-other-encoding corresponding characters, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this worked, with the help of the `codecs` module

```
begin program.
import codecs
outfile=codec.sopen("c:/temp/syntax.sps","w+","utf-8-sig")
outfile.write("some text…")
outfile.close()
end program.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know when you `SAVE AS` a syntax file in SPSS there is an option of Encoding (`Unicode (UTF-8)` vs. `Local Encoding`).

Not sure what the resolution is here but try adding to your python generated text file, on the very first line:

`* Encoding: UTF-8.`

Comment: I already tried that, but the result was the same... My SPSS, by default, is set to Unicode anyway

Comment: Is `\x85` a new line/line break? Could you use `\n` instead?

Comment: No, it is not the new line, it is the "..." Character